# Select and click workplace of SAP to load login interface via Python script

Tags: python, authentication, sap-gui

I sometimes have many duplicate documents that need to be downloaded from SAP.
Now I found some script that can access the SAP and do the boring staffs. But they focus on how to login, no description about how can select & click the workplace when open the SAP application.
In my work, I need to firstly select a defined workplace to load the **login** page, just like the picture below.

[image: Click BRP-ERP.... to load login page]

```
    def __init__(self):
        self.pathname = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"

    def main(self):

        try:
            subprocess.Popen(self.pathname)
            time.sleep(2)
            SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
```

How can I find the element of '**BRP-ERP Production**' and then click it with Python to enter the login page?
Already searched on Internet, no satisfied solution for the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

find the solution

```
connection = application.OpenConnection("BRP - ERP Production", True)
###BRP - ERP Production is the server name
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sapgui = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI').GetScriptingEngine
connection = sapgui.OpenConnection("QS3 - S/4HANA project landscape", True)
```